# SQL Server with linked server to quickbooks

Tags: sql-server, quickbooks

So I am attempting to connect my SQL Server 2012 to my Quickbooks account through the Quickbooks driver called QODBC. I am following the pages seen [here](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2458) and [here](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2814/45/qodbc-desktop-how-to-import-quickbooks-data-to-sql-server-database-local-table), however I have reached a point where I am unable to proceed.

It is just as you enter the second article and I am in the SQL Server Management Studio running this query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Tbl_Account 
FROM QRemote...Account
```

through a new query. This fails with a message

> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   [QODBC] QB Begin Session Failed. Error = 80040430, This application is unable to log into this QuickBooks company data file automatically.
>   The QuickBooks administrator must grant permission for an automatic login through the Integrated Application references. If such permission was already granted, the administrator must revoke permission, save preferences, then grant the permission again.
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "QRemote".

I have given the correct permissions to Quickbooks, and have even removed and re-granted the permissions. I cannot find anywhere that has said anything that can be done for this issue besides the re-granting the permissions, and I was wondering if anyone here has any suggestions.

Comment: You m ay have granted permissions for QB to Access SQL. But what about within QB itself that allows it to connect with SQL. It might be a setting somewher

Comment: QB is the location that I have done most of the permission changing.  I have not done as much permission swapping in the driver, but mostly in the QB itself.